# Number of days in a year Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to calculate the number of days for a dedicated year based on a date, e.g. 2015 using excel vba. 2015 should have 365 days which is a non-leap year and 2016 are 366 which is a leap year.

A date would be e.g. 01.02.2015 and based on the year 2015 I would like to know how many days are in 2015. Is there a way doing it in vba?

Comment: `datediff` function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

or

```
Public Function daysinyear(lngyear As Long) As Long
    daysinyear = DateDiff("d", DateSerial(lngyear, 1, 1), DateSerial(lngyear + 1, 1, 1))
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect that is what I was looking for.

Comment: since it is days that the op want this is less typing: `daysinyear = DateSerial(lngyear + 1, 1, 1) - DateSerial(lngyear, 1, 1)`

Comment: Perfect that is even simpler :)

Answer (score 4):

This works for most purposes e.g. 1901-2099:

```
=IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),4),365,366)
```

As @tigeravatar pointed out, for more rigorous logic try this:

```
=IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),4),365,IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),100),366,IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),400),365,366)))
```

Source: [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) handy algorithm:

> 1. if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)
> 2. else if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)
> 3. else if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)
> 4. else (it is a leap year)

Comment: Note that this isn't foolproof.  The year 1900 is not a leapyear (only every 00 year divisible by 400 is a leapyear, which is why 2000 was one)

Comment: Updated with a more full solution using this method.

Comment: Odd bit of Excel trivia. It was Lotus that originally screwed up the '1900-as-a-leap-year' calculation and never fixed it. When Excel came along, they had to intentionally make the same mistake to provide cross-platform compatibility with Lotus which was the *defacto standard* at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The [DAYS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DAYS-function-57740535-d549-4395-8728-0f07bff0b9df) was introduced with Excel 2013.

```
=DAYS(DATE(2017, 12, 31), DATE(2017, 1, 1))+1
```

The [NETWORKDAYS.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28) was introduced at the same time. Set it to include all days.

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATE(2017, 1, 1), DATE(2017, 12, 31), "0000000")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just subtract 12/31 of the year previous from 12/31 of the year desired:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),12,31)-DATE(YEAR(A2)-1,12,31)
```

[image]

Comment: or similarly: `=DATE(YEAR(A2),12,31)-DATE(YEAR(A2),1,1)+1`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking more somthing like the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for a VBA solution. Here is one that determines the number of days based on the existence of the leap day:

```
Public Function daysinyear(lngyear As Long) As Long
    daysinyear = 368 - Month(DateSerial(lngyear, 2, 29))
End Function
```